# Can I install ubuntu on Sony Viao?

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows, sony

I am planning on buying Sony Viao T series SVT13113EN Ultrabook. It comes in two versions - one with Windows 7 and the other with WIndows 8. When I asked the sony people if I cud install ubuntu alongside windows - he said there can be problems and errors. Is this true?

I've been using ubuntu and windows on my Lenovo laptop for a long time. I had no problems untill recently. My laptop sound is not working in both windows and ubuntu.

But can there be problems in laptops if we install windows and linux os side by side?

Comment: Yes, Sony does not support Linux well. You'd better stick with Lenovo. As for why that is the case, ask "the Sony people".

Comment: When something doesn't work, like sound, on both Windows and Ubuntu, most likely its hardware problem. Installing Ubuntu side by side Windows should not break hardware or Windows installation.

Comment: Ubuntu works fine on my Sony VAIO VPCEC490x

Comment: the "sony people" have to tell you that because they do not officially support it and protect themselves from liability claims that way.
For example my friend had an Acer notebook with ubuntu on it and sent it in because the wireless card was busted (completely hardware related, most likely manufacturing error) and they wouldn't replace it because it had ubuntu on it

Answer (score 1):

got a Sony Laptop, well this is a bit tricky, got Politics written all over it.

Ive got Ubuntu 13.04 installed on a brand new Sony laptop works extremely well in all parts but the backlight, but working on that. ( after reboot OS does not remember the level of backlight)
But like i said, everything else works more than good, well over to the problem:

Microsoft nowaday feels threatend by the better OS like Ubuntu (Linux), so in an attempt to stop us from choosing the OS we want, they have come up with something new, to stop us from installing Ubuntu alongside Windows, in the BIOS they have created a new way to boot up, so far only microsofts products are allowed in something they call UEFI, well even if the laptops are delivered with this option live, sinply go in to BIOS mode ((if you do not know  what youre doing get proffessional help with this) might destroy your computer, so be safe)) change this from uefi to (legacy) might be different depending on manufacturer.

Disclaimer, all of this is on your own responcebility....
Be aware that some manufacturers might not recognice their warranty after you have fiddled whit the OS / BIOS So choose manufactor wisely

Now boot Ubuntu from USB and install it, take caution so that you dont erase your Windows partition, might come in handy in the futture....

You will now get a BOOTUP start menu, simply choose Ubuntu and its on. If you want to start Microsoft Windows, until this time you will have to change the BIOS Legacy back to UEFI and it works.... Will proberbly solve this glitsh in the future, but for now..

Comment: I recommend you to update from 13.04 to 13.10 as your support will be finished in 20 days.

Comment: Thanks, will do, i did forget one thing to get the Ubuntu installation to work one must disable the Secure Boot option in Bios aswell, and yes on your own respncebility  aswell.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the Windows 8 version you will have to enter the BIOS and disable UEFI and enable legacy boot to install Ubuntu without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got done configuring a Toshiba Satellite to dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 8. Chance are you might run into some hardware incompatibility issues, but it is a given when you are working with Ubuntu. On the other hand there is a large community thus a very good that you can find a solution. Below are some suggestions.

1. I have documented a summary of steps and some good references [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399110/dual-boot-issues-with-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04/402927#402927).
2. I also have document some of the issue that I encountered and suggested solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402242/blank-screen-command-prompt-on-ubuntu-window-8-1-daul-boot-toshiba-laptop)
3. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=18F3CZveMwg&feature=youtu.be) is a YouTube video of someone installing Ubuntu along side windows 8 on a **Sony Viao**.
4. [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LokDqte3sA4) is another YouTube video on how to install Ubuntu along side windows 8.

HTH