# DUAL boot issues with windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Sony VAIO with preloaded Windows8. I  allocated a space of 16gb seperately without creating a new volume and then put the Ubuntu installation disc.I had to Boot in UEFI for using Windows,and Legacy Boot mode for using Ubuntu. Everything was fine until a few days, then the issue starts : Both the OS became too slow and the partition editor shows that Ubuntu was loaded in the partition of windows itself.. Now i formatted that allocated space of Ubuntu partition from Windows itself (normal NTFS format) inorder to reinstall Ubuntu. Even though after the format,i get a prompt to chose The OS at Boot time. I dont exactly understand the problem... Please help me out.

Comment: May I please ask you to open a terminal window, enter `sudo fdisk -l > fdisk.log 2>&1` then edit your original question and add in the fdisck.log contents?  It's OK if it runs long.

Comment: `fdisk` won't provide useful information, since the disk is almost certainly GPT, and Ubuntu 12.04's `fdisk` doesn't work with GPT. Change `fdisk -l` to `parted -l` and the command that K7AAY suggests may be useful. More broadly, it's unclear what is meant by "the partition editor shows that Ubuntu was loaded in the partition of windows itself" -- this simply makes no sense. Please clarify, ideally with reference to the `parted` output.

Comment: Even when I used to boot in the Legacy mode.. at boot time.. grub also asked to select the OS.. but Ubuntu only loaded

Answer (score 2):

I recently successfully dual boot Ubuntu 12.04 LTS / Windows 8 on a pre-loaded Toshiba Satellite C55-A5310 laptop. Following are some suggestions base on community feedback.

1. Both Ubuntu and Windows can be dual booted in UEFI mode. This is the preferred method.
2. Know your hardware. Example CPU, Graphic Card, etc. This will greatly benefit the process.
3. Create Windows 8 Recovery disk. (Cannot emphasis this any more)

Following are the summary of the steps I followed. For more detail refer to the referances below. They were a good source.

- Create Recovery Media - Cannot emphasis the importance.
- Using windows disk manage shrink windows partition
- Create boot-able drive with Ubuntu (I created a DVD, you can use USB too)
- Turn off fast boot and disable secure boot
- Run the Ubuntu installer
- Partition the empty space ( Created after shirking the Windows partition)
- Install Ubuntu
- Reboot into the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Install and Run the boot repair (I chose the following: Boot Repair => Buggy-kernel detected => Yes)
- Install Grub in PBR

As mentioned the above steps are described in greater detail in the following reference article.

I also ran into RTL8188EE wireless not detected issues to which a solution was found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397983/ubuntu12-04-realtek-rtl8188e-wireless-card-not-detected). Also blank screen after grub all was an issue which I have documented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402242/blank-screen-command-prompt-on-ubuntu-window-8-1-daul-boot-toshiba-laptop).

**References**

1. [Dual boot windows 8 and ubuntu-12-10 in uefi mode](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/03/12/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04-in-uefi-mode/)
2. [Install Ubuntu Linux alongside windows](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2013/09/install-ubuntu-linux-alongside-windows.html)
3. [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
4. [Install Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1 in 10 easy steps](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html)
5. [How to Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10](https://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=721&host=www.google.co.in&ts=1474371405&sig=AKOVD67lF-PvrdBwcYwS-NwlZGJdmNE_RQ)