# Ubuntu 14.04 installation doesn't show options to dual-boot with windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 64bit to my Acer am3400 and dual-boot with windows 7.
My hard drive already has four partitions: two small ones, the windows 7 and an empty D partition, about the same size as the windows partition. I'm thinking of installing Ubuntu to D partition (that's gonna work, right?).

I'm installing from USB and everything goes well until the installation gets to "Installation type"-part. I think it's skipping over some part, since after checking the memory and internet it just goes straight to installation type. I get no options of if I want to install alongside windows or delete windows or anything. And in the "installation type" it doesn't show anything in the box. -, + or change options don't work and only the quit, back and install now buttons do something. If i hit install now, I get an error message saying "No root file system is defined".

This all happens if I install after first going to "try without installing" -option. If i choose "install now", it doesn't even get to installation type part without showing error message (different, it says ubi-partman failed with exit code... I can get past this but it shows up at every part of installation with different exit code and finally it just stops at getting time from network server or something similar. And I still don't get to choose if I want to install alongside windows or something else).

I've tried to download ubuntu again and used a different USB stick but it doesn't work.
Does anyone have any idea of how I should proceed from here?

I'm still new to linux and ubuntu and english isn't my fist language so sorry for mistakes. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation type empty on 16.04 for a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802152/installation-type-empty-on-16-04-for-a-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

@Lowercase,

I am no ubuntu expert, but I did use a LiveCD to configure the system. I have document some of my experience at the link below.

- [DUAL boot issues with windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399110/dual-boot-issues-with-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Follow these link and see it they will benefit you as much I benefited from them. BTW make sure you backup your data and create a recoverable disk.