# Installation Type not showing any option

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, partitioning

I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot. I have an SSD and I have created a partition.
[image: screenshot of the partition list]

I have also disabled secure boot option and when I try to install Ubuntu, it doesn't show any partition on Installation Type screen. I am new to Ubuntu and trying to install it. Any help will be really great.

Comment: What should I do now? any link that can help me?

Comment: It sounds like an EFI-based system with a GPT disk, in which case the 4-primary-partition limit doesn't apply; but I'm not 100% positive of that. Please run the [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and select the "Create BootInfo Summary" option. (*DO NOT* click "Recommended Repair," at least not yet!) When asked whether to upload the report, click "Yes," and then post the URL provided here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation type empty on 16.04 for a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802152/installation-type-empty-on-16-04-for-a-dual-boot)