# "install alongside windows 10" menu never shows up when trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

And the "Installation Type" menu is empty save for "/dev/sda"
I made a partition of 2.5Gb yet it never shows up.

It gets even more complicated when it could easily detect and display all the partitions in Gparted when I last checked a week ago, now Gparted just says the whole thing is unallocated space.

My laptop's memory is GPT I think, not MBR. Someone told me that adds some difficulties but idk what that changes specifically.

Comment: The whole disk unallocated may mean that Windows FastBoot is still enabled. Get into the habit of disabling it, and then shutting down Windows properly, or you may lose your entire Windows install and all your data due to Windows' assumptions about disk usage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installation type empty on 16.04 for a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802152/installation-type-empty-on-16-04-for-a-dual-boot)