# Install Ubuntu w/o deleting Windows - Installation type almost empty

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, system-installation

New Edit:

The output of command `ls -l /dev/mapper/`

```
total 0
crw------- 1 root root 10, 236 Sep  4 20:32 control
```

---

Original Question:

I'm learning to use Ubuntu and want to install Ubuntu 18.04.3LTS in my Dell Alienware m15r2 with 2x500GB PCle M.2 SSD in RAID0. At first the step "Installation type" was totally empty and after I followed the method mentioned in [Installation type empty on 16.04 for a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802152/installation-type-empty-on-16-04-for-a-dual-boot), it shows up as in following Picture(this link).

[image]

Only two Devices detected: `/dev/nvme0n1` and `/dev/nvme1n1` Both of them are 512.1GB, so I cannot know how to get a chunk of free space w/o touching Windows.

And I don't understand under that link how to "add the following kernel argument at boot time: nvme_load=YES" and what does DELL mean by "Press 12 when you see the keyboard prompt"...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Boot from the Ubuntu USB. Use the **Try Ubuntu without Installing** option. Open a terminal and enter the following command in one line: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install dmraid`. Let the installation finish. Don't worry this will only last until you restart the computer. Now enter the following command: `ls -l /dev/mapper/`. Copy and paste the output of the last command into your question using the edit link below the question. Finally format the pasted output as code using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: Be sure to have a good backup of Windows. RAID 0 was normally used to speed up slow HDDs, not sure you get much speed increase with NVMe drives. Also only for use where data is backed up daily or more often or only from a server. If either drive fails, you lose all data.

Comment: @oldfred I also heard that... But this is the default setting and I'm not familiar with that. Do you suggest that I'd better convert the RAID0 to regular drives and install Windows again?

Comment: I don't have much experience with RAID. I will let those who know more about it comment and answer this question.

Comment: I do not really know RAID. Did see one or two users who broke the RAID, but then had to restore or install Windows to one drive & then installed Ubuntu to another drive. Some also just install Ubuntu to an external drive, so they do not have to change RAID.

Comment: @oldfred I concur with RAID-0 being the worst of the worst.  First thing I did when I got my new PC is remove the RAID-0 too.  It will cut the write speed in 2 but at a reliability of *10. (see answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAID-0 is worse than no RAID at all, as it provides no redundancy whatsoever, so if one of your NVMe drives fails, it'll take down the whole system therefore:

1. Take a full system backup using [CloneZilla Live](https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live.php) using disk-to-image
2. Shrink the partitions to allocated space +10% using [gparted Live](https://gparted.org/livecd.php) and take another full system back-up
3. Remove the RAID-0
4. Restore the System Backup from #2 to one of the NVMes
5. Install Ubuntu on the other one

Comment: Thanks for your advice and answer! At last I chose the easier way, use another external disk for Ubuntu...

Comment: That's good too!  **:-)** Ubuntu will be protected except the EFI partition, so back that up!