# cant boot windows 8 or ubuntu!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I 've recently bought a laptop with windows 8 and can't stand it. Though I need to keep it for some software I use at work..

I was advised to install ubuntu and have it set as dual boot. One completely wasted weekend later and I now cant use windows 8 or ubuntu.

Ubuntu worked fine after the install, (not done in legacy mode) but the boot files for windows were gone. After doing boot-repair and recommended, I got an error saying grub could not be installed. Now linux will not boot either without the cd.

After loads and loads of google searches everybody's answer is different and conflicting with the last..

This is really frustrating now, I'm a linux virgin and don't have any more time to waste on this. Can someone with more experience please advise how to install grub whilst booting from the livedisk

Comment: This sounds like you  need to boot linux into a live CD or USB and then once booted, you would click Try Ubuntu then install boot-repair

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could edit your question to describe some of the things you have tried and how they failed (eg error messages, system behavior, etc). This way you'll get more targeted answers.

Comment: Hi many thanks, was a frustrating evening yesterday! :) my head was fried after how many hours of nightmare..

Comment: I was following a tutorial on how to dual boot, it told me after doing the 3 partitions to put the boot loader in the same place as the windows one or dual boot would never work (im now sure this was what caused my problems??)i Tried boot-repair etc but after i got square eyes I used my liveCD and then re-installed ubuntu (remove and re-install).. i think that was the end of windows totaly, now i still have a FAT32 partition of about 600mb, the rest of the hdd is 1 big partition almost. Next time i will remember the error code like ubuntu told me :) not used to error codes being of any use..

Comment: Unfortunately i do need to run windows in some form for now so i can use my plotter and cnc machine while i learn how to just use lynux. any suggestions or good links would be much appreciated, as were your responses in the first place.  ryekayo.. my mind was so fried i didn't think to use the liveCD lol

Comment: I suggest that you re install windows. Then follow this link. http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: There are many good tutorial. Google is your friend. Some of them can be found here. http://askubuntu.com/questions/399110/dual-boot-issues-with-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04/402927#402927