# Install Grub on USB drive / Vaio Pro 13

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm somewhat inexperienced with Linux. I'm having quite a hard time booting Ubuntu 14.04 along side Windows on my Vaio Pro 13. I've tried using every method I've found on forums but no matter what, I cannot boot the Ubuntu installation after the install.

I can boot off of the Live USB and perform a successful installation, but when I reboot, the computer boots into Windows right away. After looking through the EFI partition I can see the entries that Ubuntu (and other linux distros I tried installing) but somehow they're all bypassed and Windows boots right up.

I can boot off of the usb flash drive to install Ubuntu on the machine and the installation succeeds without mistakes.

My question is, once I do install Ubuntu on a partition on the SSD, can I install grub to a USB flash drive and boot into the Ubuntu installation that way?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a common problem. Check out this link http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html. you need to get grub configured.

Comment: You can find few good references here http://askubuntu.com/questions/399110/dual-boot-issues-with-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04/402927#402927